# sine to radians or degrees in Java

Tags: java, trigonometry

I have a right triangle with two sides 3 and 4.  Obviously the hypotenuse is 5.  When I use an online calculator and enter 3 and 4 as the sides, it calculates everything else.

My question is how do you calculate angle alpha and angle beta using Java Math?  Remember, I do not know the angles, only the sides 3 and 4

```
Given a=3 and b=4,
c = 5
angle α = 36.87 deg
angleβ = 53.13 deg
h = 2.4
area = 6
perimeter = 12
```

Comment: You need to write code for it and if you face any problems while writing it, post a question.

Comment: `Math.atan()` might come useful

Comment: Look up law of sines and law of cosines.

Comment: Can you please write a title that actually describes your question?

Comment: Note that the Java functions are in radians (so you'll need to convert to radians, and then back to degrees).

Comment: There's no Java here at all. Except where you ask us to write the code for you

Comment: If you have 2 sides of a right triangle, you can calculate the hypotenuse using pythagorean theorem . With all 3 sides, you calculate any angle using "sohcahtoa" equations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really need to improve your question, showing us what you already have done, but since you are a user that is not used to post questions, take my answer as a motivation to better elaborate it.

Since you have the catheti values (`a` and `b`), to calculate the hypotenuse, you just need to apply the Pythagorean theorem:

```
double a = 3;
double b = 4;
double c = Math.sqrt( a * a + b * b );
```

Now, you should know that the `sine` function for a angle is equal to the ratio between the opposite cathetus and the hypotenuse. You also can see that you don't want the `sine` of the angle, but the angle itself! Since you can calculate de `sine` just dividing the desired cathetus by the hypotneuse, you need a way to get the angle of that `sine`. To do this, you just need to use an arc function, a.k.a. inverse trigonometric function, that deals with `sines`. The function is called `arc sine` (`Math.asin( sine )` in Java). The final detail, the Java trigonometric API deals with angles measured in radians, instead of degrees, so the return of `asin` will be the angle in radians and you will need to convert to degrees.

```
double alpha = Math.toDegrees( Math.asin( a / c ) );
double beta = Math.toDegrees( Math.asin( b / c ) );
```

You should take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle